# How to fit cell size to the content in a dataframe plot table?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to find a way to make the rows height of a Pandas DataFrame plot table fit to their content. If not possible, is there an alternative way to draw this kind of plot?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1,figsize =(8,2))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(np.random.rand(5, 3),2), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'],index=['1\na','2\na','3\na','4\na','5\na'])
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)   # Hide Ticks
df.plot(table=True, ax=ax)
fig.dpi = 600
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove every "\na" in your Dataframe index list and your problem should be solved.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1,figsize =(8,2))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(np.random.rand(5, 3),2), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'],index=['1','2','3','4','5'])
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)   # Hide Ticks
df.plot(table=True, ax=ax)
fig.dpi = 600
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to adjust the cells, to fit more text. Single line won't work for me.